# Error in Form Objects in FLUID TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

I created a custom model called `Play` and it has properties `Title` and `Body` with the getters and setters.

In one of my controller `Master` , I have the `new and create actions`

```
public function newAction(\TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay = NULL) {
    $this->view->assign('newPlay', $newPlay);
}
```

My View looks like this:

```
<table>
        <f:form action="create" name="newPlay" object="{newPlay}">
            <th>Title:</th>
            <td>
                <f:form.textfield property="title"/>
            </td>
            <th>Body:</th>
            <td>
                <f:form.textarea property="body"/>
            </td>
            </th>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <f:form.submit value="Create"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </f:form>
    </table>
```

But in my create function in controller I get this error **Required argument "newPlay" is not set.**

```
public function createAction(\TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay) {
    echo $newPlay->getBody();
    echo $newPlay->getTitle();
}
```

Am I missing something here?

**Update**

After matching the name to the object and removing the brackets of property for fields, this is the error:

**Exception while property mapping at property path "":No converter found which can be used to convert from "array" to "TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play".**

**My Solution to it**

I'm very sure there is a neat way than this

```
public function createAction() {

    $newPlayArray=$this->request->getArgument('newPlay');
    $newPlay = json_decode(json_encode($newPlayArray), FALSE);
    echo $newPlay->title;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the form must match the object

```html
<f:form action="create" name="newPlay" object="{newPlay}">
```

It is used to set the name of the fields.

**Update**

Have you set PHPDoc comments? These are required and very importan for Extbase development.
Example:

```php
/**
 * @param \TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay
 * @dontvalidate $newPlay
 */
public function newAction(\TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay = NULL) {
    $this->view->assign('newPlay', $newPlay);
}
```

Comment: It still shows me the same error! I cleared the cache as well.

Comment: You also need to remove the brackets in the property names `{title}` and `{body}` or the property will be filled with the variables value.

Comment: Do I need to convert the passed object somewhere? Please check my update

Answer (score 0):

Try to always pass an object to the view. In your case you most likely pass NULL:

```
/**
 * @param \TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay
 * @dontvalidate $newPlay
 * @return void
 */
public function newAction(\TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay = NULL) {
    if (is_null($newPlay)) {
        $newPlay = $this->objectManager->create('TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play');
    }
    $this->view->assign('newPlay', $newPlay);
}
```

Leave your form as it is and just take the object in your createAction:

```
/**
 * @param \TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay
 * @return void
 */
public function createAction(\TYPO3\Playground\Domain\Model\Play $newPlay) {
    $this->playRepository->add($newPlay);
    $this->redirect('anyAction');
}
```